# Post request returns 401 from localhost but works from postman

Tags: javascript, html, http-post, fetch-api

I am trying to send API calls via POST-Request using th JavaScript fetch-API and Basic Authorization. The request works from Postman, so the URL is correct. However, sending the request from localhost using VS Code Live Server Extension, the request returns "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 ()".

Sending the same request from localhost to a postman mock-server also works.

This is my HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
  <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>
    <input id="name" type="text" name="name" placeholder="name">
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username">
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password">
    <button type="submit" onclick=JSONTest()> Submit </button>


  <script type="text/javascript">
    JSONTest = function() {
        var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
        var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
        var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
        
        let data = {title: name};
       

    fetch("url", {
        mode: 'no-cors',
        method: "POST",
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(username + ":" + password)}, 
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
        }).then(res => {
  console.log("Request complete! response:", res);
});
    };
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information you have provided I am inclined to say it is likely a [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) issue. Without more information about the url you are trying to access it is hard to say what exactly the issue may be.

It could also have to do with the protocol being used, make sure that you are using HTTPS if it is required.

Comment: It is in fact a CORS issue. Without "mode: 'no-cors',", it throws an "has been blocked by CORS policy" error. However, when adding it, the request won't pass the authorization. Is there any way to address that?

Comment: Unfortunately as far as I know the only solution is to make the request server side and pass the response back through your server. I think there are also some workarounds using iframes or webforms but I am a bit unfamiliar with them.